# QGIS upload Ortho NAIP raster layer problem - loaded a raster file, georeferenced, however is blurry

Tags: qgis, orthophoto

Relatively new QGIS user. I am trying to correctly upload an ortho NAIP file I got from the USDA geospatial gateway. I successfully uploaded the raster layer from a .sid file of a county. As I zoom in to my area of interest, the resolution is quite blurry. What I need to do is draw plot polygons over top of the plot area in the center of this image, but it would be helpful if I can actually see the tractor tire tracks in between plots. Did I do anything wrong that created this blurry image, or is this as good as it gets?

[image: Before - 50:1 compression]
[image: After - Uncompressed digital orthoimage quarter quad]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NAIP imagery is generally 1 meter resolution (some of this year's collection was at 60cm). The MrSID compression used to create the county mosaic you downloaded from the [USDA Geospatial Data Gateway](https://gdg.sc.egov.usda.gov/) will degrade it even more. MrSID compression sacrifices image quality to achieve its compression ratio target. In short, what you have is not adequate for seeing tractor tire tracks.

For the best possible view you will need to get the original, uncompressed image(s). Those can be obtained through the Farm Service Agency's [Aerial Photography Field Office](https://www.fsa.usda.gov/programs-and-services/aerial-photography/index).

Comment: After speaking with the Aerial Photography Field Office I learned that when downloading files from the USDA Geospatial Gateway, it is the compression that hurts your clarity. Before 2016 Mr SID files were compressed 25:1 to be downloaded in a realistic size of 8 gb. With the state of North Dakota going to 60cm resolution, they 2X the compression size to 50:1, causing even blurrier images, but the end user file size stayed the same. The uncompressed images come as digital orthophoto quarter quads. My resolution is far better, though I still cannot see the tractor tires, but I can count pixels.